# How do I apply a security baseline to Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: operating-systems, windows, hardening

I've setup a Windows 2008 R2 server with an Active Directory Domain Services role. I would like to apply the Specialized Security – Limited Functionality (SSLF) security baseline to it, but am unsure how to go about this.

I have downloaded and installed Security Compliance Manager tool. I think I need to use some file from this, but am unsure which one and how to apply it to the 2008 Server. I am really new to all this so step by step guides would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Move this to Server Fault.

Comment: You'll want the GPOAccelerator and a method to test. Everything you need to know about securing server 2008 (as a baseline) can be found here: http://www.docstoc.com/docs/5089940/Windows-Server-2008-Security-Guide

Comment: @SteveSyfuhs, I'm on the fence... it is a sysadmin q, but it is about hardening the system...

Comment: I'm with @SteveSyfuhs on this one.  If the question was about specific configuration options, or looking to identify baselines, it would be more relevant here.  However, @bert48 seems to already have a baseline in mind and just needs to get it on to the system.  That's much more a "Server Admin" function than it is an "IT Security" issue.

Answer (score 2):

Has been replaced by the SCM toolkit: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fb8b981f-227c-4af6-a44b-b115696a80ac&displaylang=en

Over view of SCM toolkit: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/microsoft-security-compliance-manager-scm.aspx

SCM getting started guide: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/microsoft-security-compliance-manager-scm-getting-started.aspx

SCM frequently asked questions: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/microsoft-security-compliance-manager-scm-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx

Windows 2008 security resource book: [http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Server-2008-Security-Resource/dp/0735625042/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1294339984&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735625042)

Comment: Getting Started Guide:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/microsoft-security-compliance-manager-scm-getting-started.aspx

FAQ for SCM Toolkit: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/microsoft-security-compliance-manager-scm-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx

Comment: Baseline download links for SCM Toolkit: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/microsoft-security-compliance-manager-scm-baseline-download-help.aspx

PDF Guide for Solutions Accelerator SCM Toolkit: http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/downloads/pdf/windows_server_2008_security_guide.pdf

Decent book on 2008 security: http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Server-2008-Security-Resource/dp/0735625042/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1294339984&sr=8-1

More info on release dates: http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/faq.html#4